# Conversion Type Error: Type String cannot be converted to Integer

Tags: vb.net

Hi Guys I keep getting an Exception error that string cannot be converted to integer and not quite sure why...Ive tried adding the toString() method to many different places to try and resolve and nothing has worked...can you please just glance over this and see where I am being dumb. I am basically trying to see when a new item is found to see if it starts with all the lines in History split it at the word """URL"""

I commented just above the if statement that throws the exception.

the exact error is:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "{ "Title": "Item 1" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Inner Exception

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
Dim History = File.ReadAllLines("history.json")
Dim NewestItems = File.ReadAllLines("items.json")
Dim InitialItems = File.ReadAllLines("Init-items.json")

For x As Integer = 0 To InitialItems.Length - 1
        Dim current As String = InitialItems(0)
        Dim splitAt As String = """Url"""
        Dim index As Integer = current.IndexOf(splitAt)
        Dim output As String = current.Substring(0, index + splitAt.Length)
        Dim recurringItemFound = 0
        If Not NewestItems(x).StartsWith(output) And Not History.Contains(NewestItems(x)) Then

            If cbxRecurringItemsOff.Checked = True Then
                For Each RecurringItem In History
                    Dim indexHistory As Integer = NewestItems(x).IndexOf(splitAt)
                    Dim outputHistory As String = NewestItemss(x).Substring(0, indexHistory + splitAt.Length)
                    '********the below if statement throws an Exception error*********
                    If NewestItems(RecurringItem).StartsWith(outputHistory) Then
                        recurringItemFound = 1
                    End If
                Next
            End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` - this would have flagged some issues.

In this context, you are using `RecurringItem` as an index in the array `NewestItems` so it is trying to convert `RecurringItem` to an `Integer`. However, `RecurringItem` comes from `History` which I assume is an array of `String`. So, you are trying to use a string that you have read from a file as an integer and the program is now "chucking a whammy".

Did you really mean `NewestItems(x).StartsWith(outputHistory)`?

Comment: Yes ty eventually it came to me